# Как сделать выбор действия в слеш командах discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Увидел в чьёмто боте реализован выбор варианта,
т.е участник при вводе аргументов видет что что-то вылезло, и выберает то что ему нужно,
возможно ли это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Да, возможно. Вы можете использовать [discord.app_commands.describe()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.describe) для описания аргументов, а если аргумент не обязателен можно в функции задать аргументу значение по умолчанию.

```py
# Пример команды с обязательными аргументами
@client.tree.command()
@app_commands.describe(
    first_value='The first value you want to add something to',
    second_value='The value you want to add to the first value',
)
async def add(interaction: discord.Interaction, first_value: int, second_value: int):
    """Adds two numbers together."""
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{first_value} + {second_value}'
                                            f'= {first_value + second_value}')

# Пример команды с необязательными аргументами
# To make an argument optional, you can either give it a supported default argument
# or you can mark it as Optional from the typing standard library. This example does both.
@client.tree.command()
@app_commands.describe(member='The member you want to get the joined date from;'
                              'defaults to the user who uses the command')
async def joined(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: Optional[discord.Member] = None):
    """Says when a member joined."""
    # If no member is explicitly provided then we use the command user here
    member = member or interaction.user

    # The format_dt function formats the date time into 
    # a human readable representation in the official client
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{member} joined '
                                            f'{discord.utils.format_dt(member.joined_at)}')
```

Советую вам полностью прочитать оригинал кода который находится [здесь](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/ee71366f7236295848086846179fef2165d41010/examples/app_commands/basic.py) и лицензирован под лицензией `MIT`, текст которой находится [здесь](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rapptz/discord.py/master/LICENSE).

Ниже находится само выполнение команды в клиенте Discord-а.
[image: Команда с необязательным аргументом]

И с обязательными аргументами:

[image: Команда с обязательными аргументами]