# Как создать необязательный аргумент

Tags: python, discord.py

Не понимаю как сделать необязательный аргумент для слеш команды в discord.py v2. Если я делаю аргумент для команды, он автоматически обязателен для заполнения. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы он был необязателен.

```
#-- Команда чтобы написать человеку в лс --
@tree.command(name="ls_user", description="Написать определённым людям в лс")
async def message_user(ctx, title: str, text: str, url_image: str, people_id: str):
    if title == None:
        embed_send = discord.Embed(
            description=text
        )
    elif text == None:
        embed_send = discord.Embed(
            title=title
        )
    else:
        embed_send = discord.Embed(
            title=title,
            description=text
        )
    if url_image != None:
        embed_send.set_image(url=url_image)
    with io.StringIO(people_id) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            for i in row:
                y = int(i)
                r = bot.get_user(y)
                await r.send(embed=embed_send)
    CHANNEL_LOGS = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_LOGS_ID)
    embed_log = discord.Embed(
        title = "Отправка в лс",
        description = f"Загаловок: {title}\nТекст: {text}\nURL-картинки: {url_image}\nЛюди: {people_id}",
        colour = 0x66CDAA
    )
    await CHANNEL_LOGS.send(embed=embed_log)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы аргумент был необязателен, можно поставить ему значение по умолчанию, например, в вашем случае, `url_image=''`. Обратите внимание, что аргументы со значениями по умолчанию должны быть в конце списка аргументов из-за синтаксиса python, т.е. в вашем случае url_image должен идти после people_id.
Подобный вопрос уже был задан, вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1448958/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%85-discord-py).

Comment: Чтобы задать значение по умолчанию, нужно использовать `Optional`, что написано в другом вопросе, а вы это указали, но это помогло мне, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [**здесь**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/slash-commands.md#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) про работу с аргументами в `slash`-командах.

Если вкратце, то в качестве аннотации типа лучше указывать не базовые типы, а экземпляр класса `discord.Option`, один из параметров которого позволяет сделать аргумент необязательным:

```py
from discord import Option

@bot.slash_command()
async def test(ctx, arg: Option(str, required=False)):
    . . .
```

**Опять же повторюсь, что полный разбор со всеми примерами доступен по ссылке выше**